# Is there an pandas function to count element occurring after specific words?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df
['ch*', 'co*', 'DePe*', 'DePe*', 'DePe*', 'pm*', 'tpm*', 'lep*']
['ch*', 'co*', 'DePe*', 'DePe*', 'DePe*', 'am*', 'te*', 'qe*','te*']
['ch*', 'co*', 'DePe*', 'ch*', 'DePe*', 'DePe*', 'tpm*', 'lep*']
['ch*', 'DePe*', 'eeae*', 'ps*', 'er*']
Name: df, Length: 4, dtype: object
```

i need to count items occurring after last instance of 'DePe*' (left to right)
i am looking for outcome like this.

```
df                                                                    count
['ch*', 'co*', 'DePe*', 'DePe*', 'DePe*', 'pm*', 'tpm*', 'lep*']      3
['ch*', 'co*', 'DePe*', 'DePe*', 'DePe*', 'am*', 'te*', 'qe*','te*']  4
['ch*', 'co*', 'DePe*', 'ch*', 'DePe*', 'DePe*', 'tpm*', 'lep*']      2
['ch*', 'DePe*', 'eeae*', 'ps*', 'er*']                               3
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `apply` with lambda function and `index` of reversed `lists`, it working nice, because lists are 0 based indexed in python:

```
df['count'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x[::-1].index('DePe*'))
print (df)

                                                   A  count
0   [ch*, co*, DePe*, DePe*, DePe*, pm*, tpm*, lep*]      3
1  [ch*, co*, DePe*, DePe*, DePe*, am*, te*, qe*,...      4
2   [ch*, co*, DePe*, ch*, DePe*, DePe*, tpm*, lep*]      2
3                      [ch*, DePe*, eeae*, ps*, er*]      3
```

If possible some value not exist is possible specify value in `try-except` statement:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return x[::-1].index('DePe*')
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan #or return 0

df['count'] = df['A'].apply(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `list.index` with `reversed`:

```
my_df['count'] = [list(reversed(l)).index('DePe*') for l in my_df['df']]

                                                  df  count
0   [ch*, co*, DePe*, DePe*, DePe*, pm*, tpm*, lep*]      3
1  [ch*, co*, DePe*, DePe*, DePe*, am*, te*, qe*,...      4
2   [ch*, co*, DePe*, ch*, DePe*, DePe*, tpm*, lep*]      2
3                      [ch*, DePe*, eeae*, ps*, er*]      3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to python so this solution might not be what you're looking for. But I think this works:

```
l1 = ['ch*', 'co*', 'DePe*', 'DePe*', 'DePe*', 'pm*', 'tpm*', 'lep*']
count=0
for x in l1:
    if x == 'DePe*':
        count=0
    else:
        count+=1
print (count)
```

Comment: Nevermind, just saw that other answers have been posted.